# load actual photo of contact in android 2.3.*

Tags: android, photo, android-contacts

Still facing with problem of loading actual contact's photos in android 2.3.*... Tried many different ways but can't to get latest photo from phonebook. My last code:

```
 Uri uri =   getPhotoUri(context, contact.getPhoneBookContactId()); 
 Picasso.with(context).load(uri).error( R.drawable.contact_icon ).into(imageViewLowGB);
```

where getPhotoUri:

```
public static Uri getPhotoUri(Context context,final int contactId) {
        try {
            Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId + " AND "
                            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='"
                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null,
                    null);
            if (cur != null) {
                if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    return null; // no photo
                }
            } else {
                return null; // error in cursor process
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e( ImageManager.class.getSimpleName(), "error getPhotoUri" +e.getMessage() );
            return null;
        }
        Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId( ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,contactId );
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(person, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    }
```

This code give me photo, but if change photo, old photo loading again and again (( 
Please, someone help me...This problem only on 2.3.* versions(